# What are these bytes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, byte, aes

In the code(below) I don't really understand the purpose of this part `{&H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
                 &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65}` . What are these bytes for? and can I change it? I am not familiar with encryption(Noob here) and that line made me confused. And is there a definition for this? it looks like an ASCII code to me. Thanks!

```
Dim x As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() { &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
             &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65}, 1000)
```

Comment: It spells "Van Medvede" in ASCII.  Don't understand the significance.

Comment: What I mean is that it looks like the &H76 is a character or something. I am really not familiar what is that set for

Comment: Yes, it's a capital "V" in ASCII.  The crypto function reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx), if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). It's used as a random key to hash a particular bit of data (for example, a password).

Normally without salt, if you hash a simple password string, it can be unhashed by comparing it against rainbow table. But adding salt, it turns a simple string into a more complex string before it is hashed.

It's normally meant to be a random array of bytes. So your salt is hexidecimal 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65.

You can randomise the salt array by using the following snippet.

```
Dim salt1(8) As Byte
Using rngCsp As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    rngCsp.GetBytes(salt1)
End Using
```

Comment: is there any eq in PHP?